# tkk passing parameters to callbacks

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

I'm working on a tkinter ttk interface to automate/facilitate some relatively complex reporting.

I have a function which performs a complex data scan across a directory. To execute the function you click a button widget in the toolbar:

```
fileMenu.add_command(label="Generate Report",command=ScanActiveProjects)
```

However I would like to reuse the code in this function by adding an additional parameter (simple=True/False) so that I can map a partial and a complete execution of the function to individual buttons.

I thought that I could do this fairly simply like this:

```
fileMenu.add_command(label="Generate Management Report",command=ScanActiveProjects(simple=True)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Generate Detailed Report",command=ScanActiveProjects(simple=False)
```

The result of this is that the button is automatically pressed on starting up the program - which I don't understand. So my questions are:

1) Why is the button automatically pressed when adding the (simple=True)/(simple=False)parameters?

2) How can I bind a callback function to a button but have the button provide a specific constructor parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The button is automatically pressed since you do a function call to `SendActiveProjects` in the `add_command`.
2. You can use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to do what you want.

Comment: The simplest solution was to change:

command=ScanActiveProjects(True)

to:

command= lambda: ScanActiveProjects(False)